# Go to line from stack trace in the output window of Visual Studio (.NET Core)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Is it possible to 'go to line' from a stack trace in the output window in Visual Studio when running a .NET core project - or is there an extension that makes this possible?

I am used to using other development environments with this functionality (JetBrains IDEs, Unity3D), and think that it is such obvious functionality that I might just be overlooking something.

--

Update (in response to Sebastian L):
it seems that menu is disabled for me when I right click on a stack line
[Output Right Click Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBgd6.png)

Comment: that is already possible. In your Output you can just rightclick and then jump to the code

Comment: Did you try double left click?

Comment: @Albondi yes - double left click just selected the word under the cursor :/ I'm wondering if this is a configuration issue with my default Visual Studio 2017 setup (likely) or whether it is unsupported functionality in .NET Core (less likely but possible).